# Importing access keys and secrets to an Android device

Tags: android, import, key, storage, account

I've got an app that can save stuff you like to [Google Storage for Developers](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/).  Assuming, of course, that you have an account and associated access keys.  Their web based key management tool allows you to create keys and associated secrets.  My question is regarding how a user can most easily install these in their copy of my app, allowing them to use the cloud storage.

A key is a 20 character alphanumeric string, and an associated secret is a 40 character Base-64 encoded string.  It is clearly impractical for the user to enter these manually.  Cut and paste across activities seems way awkward to me.  How do you suggest getting two strings from a web page to two activity EditText fields - or to a tmp file I can read and then dispose - or ??

thanks.

Comment: How about creating an api for getting the values?

Comment: @jos, I'd need you to be much more specific.

Comment: Do Google provide an API to retrieve Google Storage for Developers access keys and accounts?

Comment: What I meant was using an API from google storage if they have or create one that suits your needs.

Comment: @joseph and @jos ... clearly the right route if its available ... I'm off to look.

Comment: I am not able to identify a Google API for getting storage keys and secrets.  At this point a screen scrape is looking required.  And of course that will require Google account authentication...

Comment: jos you were first but "creating an api" means to me writing the code  and is implicit if I write the code.  Joseph, move your comment to an answer and I'll award you the rep.  In the short term I'm unable to say any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to go about it would be the [API from Google](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a web page, there are these values are residing, you can download it, parse, and get these values.

Comment: This is feasible.. you win if nobody provides an even better answer.  TY.

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't look like Google provides an API specifically for getting keys, your best bet would probably be to use an HTTP GET to pull the web page containing the keys and secret keys.

If you need to be authenticated with Google to do this (presumably you'd have to be), you could use [SignPost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) to handle OAuth and make secure HTTP requests. After you pull the page, parse through the HttpResponse content and store the keys in a text file or a SharedPreferences file.